# how to add a cron express into JVM arguments

Tags: java, cron, jvm, jvm-arguments

I try to use shell to run java application:

```
nohup java -Xmx1024m -Dabc=abc -Dcron="0 0 2 * * ?" -cp xxx.jar;yyy.jar 2&>1
```

but there are two problems:

1.`-Dcron="0 0 2 * * ?"` contains space so JVM thinks they are separate.JVM says"could not find main class 0"

2.`*` will be replaced by file name.

how to add a cron express into JVM arguments？

Comment: Does `'-Dcron=0 0 2 * * ?'` work (with the whole argument in single quotes)? What operating system and what terminal/shell do you use? Aside from this, you still need to specify a main class.

Comment: double quotation marks should work since it is referred in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html : _If value is a string that contains spaces, then you must enclose the string in double quotation marks:

java -Dmydir="some string" SomeClass_

Comment: Maybe `"-Dcron=\"0 0 2 * * ?\""` or just `-Dcron=\"0 0 2 * * ?\"`could also work (especially if the OP uses a bash-like shell and it seems so because `*` is expanded).

Comment: nothing worked for me. Do anyone have a solution for this?